# device.uuid undefined in PhoneGap on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing a PhoneGap application that sends requests to a central database. It needs to be able to identify the unique devices that connect to it.

PhoneGap's [`device.uuid` property](http://docs.phonegap.com/docs/device) would seem to do the trick. On webOS and iPhone, I get back a unique string of alphanumeric characters, which will satisfy my need. However, the Android devices I've tested (Motorola Droid and the Android SDK emulator, both running Android 2.1) return "undefined" as the `device.uuid`.

`device.platform` and `device.name` return correct values on all three platforms, so the problem doesn't have to do with the `device` object itself (it's defined in the code blocks where I use it).

Is this an Android limitation? A problem with PhoneGap?

Is there any other way to get such a globally unique identifier if not through `device.uuid`?

EDIT: It appears that the `deviceready` event is never getting fired, which needs to happen before the `device.uuid` property becomes available.

Comment: the deviceready function is not getting fired 'cause this code ` if ( ( state == 'loaded' || state == 'complete' ) && DeviceInfo.uuid != null )` I'm also struggling with this :C

Comment: node that device.uuid is truly unique only on iOS, on Android it's a random number generated on system boot - [check the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on Phonegap version and/or device, you might need to install the plugin explicitly. In our project, device was present but device.uuid was undefined. Running `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` fixed the issue in our case.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet found a solution for this, but it is worth noting that this issue is fixed in Android 2.2. But other than that, you'll have to find some other way of getting a unique device identifier if the device is running 2.1 or earlier.

Comment: Apparently this still happens on my Archos tablet, which runs **Android 2.2.1**

Comment: It still happens also on a HTC Flyer with **Android 3.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was working previously, and I eventually traced the problem back to the manifest permissions.

If `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is not enabled, `deviceready` will not fire, and `device.uuid` will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

first installation of device plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```

and in my index.js i have this:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },   
    getDeviceInfo: function() {
        var aio = new Object();
        aio.agent = device.platform + "," + device.version + "," + device.model;
        aio.deviceid = device.uuid;
        return aio;
    }
};
app.initialize();

module.controller('AppController',function($scope) {
    console.log('GOOOO');
    ons.ready(function() {
        console.log("ons ready");

        var appInfoObj = app.getDeviceInfo();
        console.log("Agent: " + appInfoObj.agent);
        console.log("UUID: " + appInfoObj.deviceid);
    });
});
```