# DeviceInfo.uuid is undefined

Tags: android, cordova, uuid

edit: I realised that PhoneGap is stuck in an endless loop because `DeviceInfo.uuid is undefined`. Though I don't know how to fix that it nails down the problem.

The fact that this behaviour occurs on my android simulator (v3.0) as well as on the asus Eee pad (android v3.2) let me assume there's something going on with PhoneGap and Android.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877938/device-uuid-undefined-in-phonegap-on-android) thread is discussing the same issue - without result :C

*original question:*

As simple as it is: it just won't start.

```
$(function(event){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady false); 
});
function onDeviceReady(){
  console.log("go!");
}
```

When logging `PhoneGap.available` it's (surprisingly) return: `false`! However the code is working on Android 2.2 and iPad as well.
Anyone knows any issues with PhoneGap on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a quick test with the Jquery mobile plugin it seems, that phonegap 1.1 can find the UUID find, but phonegap 1.2 cannot. It seems they regressed a little with the past update

Comment: phonegap's irc channel just suggested to open a bug ticket for it - seems like there's nothing we can do about it.